# CameraX preview is showing FRONT camera, taken picture is BACK camera

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to take selfie picture using cameraX.

Preview works fine and show the front camera, but the actual captured image is from the back camera.

How to fix that problem?

Have anyone faced the same problem before?

Comment: This isn't a general tech help desk; please see the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Every UseCase config need to be defined with

```
setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
```

Setting it to the preview only won't help for face recognition or image capture.